# surface integral and vector surface integral

Tags: vectors, surface-integrals

What is the difference between [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfaceIntegrals.aspx)  surface integral and [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfIntVectorField.aspx)  vector surface integral? When can I use the first surface integral instead of the vector surface integral and when cannot?

Comment: It depends whether the function you try to integrate is a vector field $\vec{F}(x,y,z) = (F_1(x,y,z),F_2(x,y,z),F_3(x,y,z))^T$ or a scalar field $f(x,y,z)$. (I gave example in 3D but this can be generalized)

Comment: @Zubzub How do I know my function is a vector field or a scalar field? I got confused because I saw the surface integral is applied on a torus as a scalar field in the Khan academy [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9k97m8oWnaY) but actually the vector form is used in the derivation.

Comment: In the video he does a scalar field surface integral. Actually the field is simply $f(x,y,z) = 1$ and is integrating over the surface he drew,.The main difference between scalar field and vector field surface integration is the dot product that occurs between the normal vector and the vector field. Here there is no dot product, so it it a scalar field integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place get a modern advanced calculus text. What I see in your links is somewhere between "Bronstein-Semendjajew" and "Schaum's Outline". Both were already well seasoned  when I studied maths  in the 1950s.

The difference between the two kinds of integrals is the following: In the first integral a tiny piece of surface (a "surface element") just has some tiny area, whereas in the second its spacial orientation, resp., the direction of the positive normal, plays a rôle as well.

Which kind of integral you have to set up depends on the concrete differential-geometric or physical situation at stake. Here are some examples, whereby I'm referring to a parametric representation
$$(u,v)\mapsto{\bf x}(u,v)$$ of the surface $S$ in question:

If you have to compute the total surface area of $S$ then it's just the scalar surface element $${\rm d}\omega=|{\bf x}_u\times{\bf x}_v|\>{\rm d}(u,v)\ .$$
If the surface is made of some material with density (weight per unit area) $\sigma$, and you need the total potential energy of $S$ with respect to sea level $x_3=0$ then you have to integrate
$$\sigma\> x_3\>{\rm d}\omega=\sigma \>x_3(u,v)\>|{\bf x}_u\times{\bf x}_v|\>{\rm d}(u,v)\ .$$
If there is a fluid field ${\bf x}\mapsto{\bf v}({\bf x})$ given, and you want to know how much fluid passes through the "virtual" surface $S$ per second then it plays a rôle whether the field hits the different parts of $S$ orthogonally or tangentially. Physical considerations then show that you have to integrate
$${\bf v}\cdot d\vec\omega={\bf v}\bigl({\bf x}(u,v)\bigr)\cdot\bigl({\bf x}_u(u,v)\times{\bf x}_v(u,v)\bigr)\>{\rm d}(u,v)$$
over $S$. The last equation is sometimes written as
$${\bf v}\cdot d\vec\omega={\bf v}\cdot {\bf n}\>{\rm d}\omega={\bf v}\bigl({\bf x}(u,v)\bigr)\cdot{\bf n}(u,v)\>|{\bf x}_u\times{\bf x}_v|\>{\rm d}(u,v)\ ,$$
whereby the latter form contains superfluous squareroots.

Comment: Is the surface integral over vector field (the 3rd one) a generalization of a surface integral over scalar field (2nd one)?